Deploy proxy upgrade pattern contract using hardhat ignition
I have a contract like this:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC721/ERC721Upgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

contract MyToken is Initializable, ERC721Upgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable {

    function initialize(address initialOwner) initializer public {
        __ERC721_init("MyToken", "MTK");
        __Ownable_init(initialOwner);
    }
}

Question: How to write a script to deploy this contract using hardhat-ignition?

Recently, someone asked a question regarding the deployment of upgradable contracts using hardhat-ignition on the Hardhat Discord Server,  and they've responded this:

Hardhat Ignition does not provide explicit proxy contract support. It
is expressible in our module API. We are currently working on a guide
to using Ignition with upgradeable contracts, it is in PR review, but
you can see the example here:
https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat-ignition/tree/upgradeable-example-project/examples/upgradeable

Here's the screenshot for the same:

And this is the message link.

Proxy upgradeable pattern need proxy contract(where we store data).In implementation contract function initialize(constructor in common contract) we send args to start work with implementation.
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies
And your variant not work with this contract pattern

Apologies for misunderstanding. I've changed the answer. Please check.

Thanks for solution
